# Why deployed (concatenated, minified) AngularJS + RequireJS application is not working?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

[Here is my project on github](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/puzometr) (it is really small, don't worry, just example). I provide it, so you can open any file , I am talking about).

I have no problems when I open my application without js/css concatenation and minification. Routes and controllers works as expect.

If I use deployment, application is not working. There is no 404 errors, no java script errors. I see what I expect in fiddler. Everything looks correct: styles.min.css are being loaded and bootstrap.js.

To deploy my application I use Grunt. This is my [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/puzometr/blob/master/Gruntfile.js). Here is code of requirejs task:

```
requirejs: {
  js: {
    options: {
      uglify2: {
        mangle: false
      },
      baseUrl: "public/js",
      mainConfigFile: "public/js/bootstrap.js",
      name: 'bootstrap',
      out: "build/js/bootstrap.js",
      optimize: 'uglify2'
    }
  }
},
```

Why I am getting this problem?

Max: what is exact problem, what I am doing wrong there?

Min: how I can at least debug my minified code? All debuggers and `console.log` are being removed from the code. If I have debuggers I at least can watch where exactly code fails...

UPD

[Note](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/puzometr/tree/master/public/js/main/views), How I include views... Can this approach cause problems?

Also, I cant find myCtrl in bootstrap.js (output file). Why? Looks like it is not included there...

Thank you

Comment: About close: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." – I have desired behaviour, I specified the problem and I have example.

Comment: ... yes but it's not **in the question itself**

Comment: To clarify: does this work if you set `optimize: 'none'`? Is it the requirejs optimization that causes the problem, or the minification using uglify?

Comment: *"Min: how I can at least debug my minified code?"* sourcemaps.

Comment: @KevinB I can even beautify code with chrome dev tools. Grunt removes all debuggers, so I can't debug code.

Comment: @jperezov no, it doesn't work even with no optimize

Comment: The requirejs optimizer concatenates everything into one file. Are you including this file with a `script` tag? If there's no errors, it's likely you're not including the script.

Comment: I checked it in fidder. File is included.

Comment: Updated question with note.

Answer (score 3):

Because your dependencies are not having string counterparts:

```
module.controller('main.myCtrl3', function ($scope) {
    $scope.debug = function () {
      console.log('debug', $scope.$id);
    }
  })
```

you need to changed everywhere to

```
 module.controller('main.myCtrl3',['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.debug = function () {
          console.log('debug', $scope.$id);
        }
      }])
```

Probably obfuscator changes `$scope` to smth like `s` and angular doesn't know what dependency to inject

Comment: The `mangle: false` option for uglify actually prevents variable names from being changed.

Comment: Yes, you can just minify without obfuscation

Comment: My point was that OP _is_ using `mangle: false` in the code snippet used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't [handling  minification](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification), e.g. in /public/js/main/controllers/myCtrl.js

```
module.controller('main.myCtrl', function ($scope) {});
```

should be

```
module.controller('main.myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}]);
```

Comment: I thought `mangle: false` option wouldn't minify parameters of the functions